# Ошибка при отправке запроса через модуль requests

Tags: python, get, requests

Попытался отправить **GET запрос** на свой личный сайт и получаю вот такие ошибки. Если отправляю запрос к примеру **на сайт гугла, то всё ок.**
Может проблема очевидная, но я еще совсем мал в этом:)

```
import requests 

req = requests.get('https://itconts.ru/')

File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер фильтрует запросы.
Добавьте заголовок `User-Agent`, чтобы получить доступ.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


def main():
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 YaBrowser/19.10.3.281 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get('https://itconts.ru/', headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
200
```

Comment: Скажите, а почему я получаю ответ без user-agent  если посылаю запрос к google, а к своему сайту не получаю?

Comment: @Владислав Это у Вас спросить нужно :) По умолчанию модуль `requests` посылает следующий `User-Agent`: `python-requests/2.22.0`. И это отлично работает в большинстве случаев. Попробуйте посмотреть настройки своего `frontend`-сервера. Может, у Вас есть какие-то дополнительные фильтры, что-то вроде `fail2ban`?